# How to get a hash value by numeric index

Tags: ruby, hash

Have a hash:

```
h = {:a => "val1", :b => "val2", :c => "val3"}
```

I can refer to the hash value:

```
h[:a], h[:c]
```

but I would like to refer by numeric index:

```
h[0] => val1
h[2] => val3
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Beware of Ruby version differences when using `values`: 1.8.x does *not* have any ordering, while newer Ruby have insertion-ordering.

Comment: hashes are semantically unordered; if you need array-like indexing, perhaps you want a different data structure, or a class that supports both mechanisms.

Comment: @Eevee However, they have a well-defined order in recent Ruby version. Now, if this should be relied upon for an algorithm .. is another question entirely.

Comment: hence "semantically"  :)  addition-ordering is a terribly weak substitute for an actual ordered structure.  i wouldn't rely on it even in PHP, where it's practically touted as a core feature.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
h = {:a => "val1", :b => "val2", :c => "val3"}
keys = h.keys

h[keys[0]] # "val1"
h[keys[2]] # "val3"
```

Comment: Please see my benchmarks below. Using `[h[h.keys[…]]` is a bit slow to be the best solution.

Comment: @mudasobwa 's solution also makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 38):

`h.values` will give you an array requested.

```
> h.values
# ⇒ [
#  [0] "val1",
#  [1] "val2",
#  [2] "val3"
# ]
```

**UPD** while the answer with `h[h.keys[0]]` was marked as correct, I’m a little bit curious with benchmarks:

```
h = {:a => "val1", :b => "val2", :c => "val3"}
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { 1_000_000.times { h[h.keys[0]] = 'ghgh'} } 
  x.report { 1_000_000.times { h.values[0] = 'ghgh'} }
end  

#
#       user     system      total        real
#   0.920000   0.000000   0.920000 (  0.922456)
#   0.820000   0.000000   0.820000 (  0.824592)
```

Looks like we’re spitting on 10% of productivity.

Comment: nice explanation :) `+1` to you also.

Answer (score 5):

So you need both array indexing and hash indexing ?

If you need only the first one, use an array.

Otherwise, you can do the following :

```
h.values[0]
h.values[1]
```