# Displaying a method from a model into a view (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this information on a rails app that I wish to display, but I want to manipulate it a little bit and change things up with it.  The information is stored in a the database.  Now i'm looking at my show.html.haml page and creating a table with this information.

In the DB it is stored as

```
{
"images" => true,
"age" => true,
"position" => true
}
```

I can also pull this up in the console by simply typing

```
player.last.information
```

So with that in mind, in my haml file I have

```
%dd @player.information
```

and I get all the information that I need.  However, I want to separate them a little bit.  Doing some research on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131234/how-to-get-a-hash-value-by-numeric-index) I was able to break up the information in the console line by line.  However I'm having transferring them from my terminal into code.

I'm trying to start out very simple by in my model going simply

```
def information
  @player.information
end
```

and then in my show.html.haml file assuming it is just as easy as this, and not having any luck.  If anything this is my question. How am I able to get a method that was created in my model to appear in my view?

```
%dd :information
```

I have not touched anything in my controller. I don't think I need to do anything with it, (although certainly could be wrong) Would anybody be able to take a quick look at this for me?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this bit of code that you have

```
def information
  @player.information
end
```

will throw a Stack Error (and actually, it'd probably break on the `@player` instance being used *inside* it's own instance method before it even got to the Stack Error). If you absolutely *had to* override `information`, for example if `information` was a string and you required that it was always lower-cased, you could define the method like so:

```
def information
  read_attribute(:information).downcase
end
```

However, this would typically be discouraged. You'll be better served to leave your attributes alone, so that you can always get the raw content of the attribute when you need it and have supplementary methods if you want some particular formatting of the attribute.

For example, if you need the `information` attribute broken out, perhaps formatting all of the keys to be in a sentence, it'd be better to have something like this:

```
def formatted_information
  self.information.keys.to_sentence.titleize
end
```

which would give you the following output:

```
"Images, Age, And Position"
```

by doing `@player.formatted_information`.

Of course, I'm not familiar with exactly what kind of formatting you're wanting to do to that hash but sky's the limit, so go crazy.

---

#### Side Question

Also, I'd be curious to know why you're storing a hash of values in an `information` attribute, instead of just having each of the keys in that attribute be it's own attribute - i.e. `@player.images`, `@player.age`, and `@player.position`?

Comment: Hi @jeffdill2 thank you so much for you wonder explanation.   I am actually considering breaking up each value. However can't as of right now. (it's more of a group project, and i'm one small part).

Comment: Ultimately though, i'm not sure how to display that information from the model on the view.  I know that sounds elementary, but thats honestly the problem that i'm having right now. It seems like i have no problem displaying information on a view from a database, but having troubles pulling information from additional methods and such.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. In what way are you currently displaying any database data in a view? If you could update your question with an example view and it's corresponding controller, that'd be helpful.